# Understanding Faster rcnn

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, detection

I'm trying to understand fast(er) RCNN and following are the questions I'm searching for:

1. To train, a FastRcnn model do we have to give bounding box
   information in training phase.
2. If you have to give bonding box information then what's the role of
   ROI layer.
3. Can we use a pre-trained model, which is only trained for classification, not 
   object detection and use it for Fast(er) RCNN's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answers:

1.- Yes.

2.- The ROI layer is used to produce a fixed-size vector from variable-sized images. This is performed by using max-pooling, but instead of using the typical n by n cells, the image is divided into n by n non-overlapping regions (which vary in size) and the maximum value in each region is output. The ROI layer also does the job of proyecting the bounding box in input space to the feature space.

3.- Faster R-CNN  MUST be used with a pretrained network (typically on ImageNet), it cannot be trained end-to-end. This might be a bit hidden in the paper but the authors do mention that they use features from a pretrained network (VGG, ResNet, Inception, etc).

Comment: Thanks for explaining every point. It has reduced my confusion. Just one last question. Is there a way that I can do Object Detection without providing bounding box in my training data. Data set in which I want to perform Object Detection doesn't contain exact coordinates of the object in the image.

Comment: @Ahmad.Masood Not with Faster R-CNN, what you want is called weakly supervised object detection, and requires different algorithms, and doesn't work as well as having proper bounding boxes in the dataset. Just label your data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.